# how can i include a container view in a uiscrolview?

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

i have an project in xcode where i have to include a container view (iOS 6) in a UIScrollView. How do i have to do that? If i put a container view in a UIScrollView it does nothing (it let not show a scroll bar or something). If i put an UIImageView in it, it doesn't work too. My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 2304)];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn off auto layout, that will help